# How to pass global variable via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have three files:

`index.php`
`ajax.php`
`function.php`

I want to pass a global variable from `index.php` to `function.php` via `ajax.php`.
So the alert message in `index.php` should be "2". But in fact, the result is "1" because `function.php` does not know the `$global_variable`.

Here is the code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$global_variable = 1;
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
include 'function.php';

$result = process_my_variable(1);
echo $result;
?>
```

**function.php**

```
<?php
function process_my_variable($new_variable) {
    global $global_variable;
    $result = $global_variable + $new_variable;

    return $result;
}
?>
```

I do not want to pass the global variable to ajax call, because my real project has many variable like this, and they should not to display because of security.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data:{
             global_variable:<?php echo $global_variable?>
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

You can send it with data object to ajax.php page

and at ajax.php page you can fetch it by:

```
<?php
include 'function.php';
$global_var=$_POST['global_variable'];
$result = process_my_variable($global_var);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`index.php` and `ajax.php` (with the included `function.php`) are *different programs*. They do not share variables.

You either need to store the data somewhere that both programs can get at it (such as in a SESSION) or pass the data from `index.php` to the browser, and then send it to `ajax.php` in the query string or POST body of the Ajax request.